# How to do the 3 checks on a partially ordered set

Tags: relations

I have a task to check if a relation is a partially ordered set. I know i have to check if it's:

let $S$ be a set and $\mathcal{R} $ is a relation:

1. Reflexive ( $ (s,s) \in \mathcal{R} \forall s \in S$ )
2. Antisymetric ( $\forall s,t \in S: (s,t) \in \mathcal{R} \space and \space (t,s) \in \mathcal{R} \space \Rightarrow s = t  $ )
3. Transitive ( $ \forall r,s,t \in S: (s,t),(t,r) \in \mathcal{R} \space \Rightarrow (s,r) \in \mathcal{R} $ )

But i'm having some troubles actually doing this. I am confusing myself. Can you help me going by maybe checking the reflexive property?

I have to check:

$ \mathcal{R} = \{ (m,n),(m',n') \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} : n < n' \space or \space (n=n' \space and \space m \leq m') \}$

I would very much appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: As you know, you have three things to check. Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I am starting with the reflexive property, but i can't generalist the condition for my specific example.

Comment: Your goal is *not* to generalize anything. It is to prove the reflexivity holds in your *particular* case.

Comment: Yes. But i'm not sure how to mathematically & formally show that my relation either have the reflexive property or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your relation is reflexive because, if $(m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2$, then $n=n$, and $m\leqslant m$. Therefore, by definition of $\mathcal R$, $\bigl((m,n),(m,n)\bigr)\in\mathcal R$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: This was exactly what i was hoping for. The example you provide helps me understand the 3 conditions and how to use them in my case. Thank you very much!

I just used this to conclude it's antisymmetric as well. Have a great day José

Comment: @PernkDernets You're welcome.